# II operator in if condition works strange

Tags: go

I'm totally new in terms of go and for practice I decided to write a few simple apps. Quite fast I got into weird problem:

```
sum := 0
for j:= 0; j<10; j++ {
   if (j%5 == 0) || (i%3 == 0) {
      fmt.Println(j)
      sum += j
   }
}
```

Obviously I want to sum up all the numbers divisible by 5 or by 3 lower than 10. But when I run it I get:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
45
```

The weird part is it works fine if I check for divisibility only by 3 or only by 5...

Comment: Oh, sorry. The problem I have is with `II` - I pasted with bitwise OR only by accident because I was trying to find out what's going on.

Comment: How is defined i?

Answer (score 1):

I don't how know how is defined the `i` variable but change it to j it works as expected, take a look on this [go playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/5rnq88S2X6)

Comment: Jesus... you can imagine that `i` is in outer loop and it was just a typo... :)

Comment: So your issue is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Use `||` instead of `|` in the if statement.

`||`
is "logical or" which is what you want.

Once you have fixed that issue, also change the "i" variable to "j" because that's what you want to compare against.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The problem I have is with `II` - I pasted with bitwise OR only by accident because I was trying to find out what's going on. –